# iPhone 5s won't mount on Mac

Tags: iphone, osx-mavericks

I have a new iPhone 5s. I want to copy the photos that I have taken directly into my computer. 
When plugged into my Mac running 10.9.4 it doesn't recognize it.

Do I need additional software for it to mount?

Answer (score 1):

No additional drivers are needed, just launch iPhoto;
then in prefs you can set whether it (or any other capable app) should auto-launch if you plug in your iPhone.
Otherwise, it will only offer to import photos if you manually launch one of these apps, & plug in the iPhone.

[image: iPhoto prefs]